# Dijkstra's Algorithm in Multicast Routing

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra, multicastsocket

EDIT: I reconstructed the question

I was assigned a project where I need to simulate multicast routing and put labels in the network. The teacher was very vague as to what kind of simulation we needed so that is where I got confused. I'll outline the requirement of the simulation.

***In your simulation, you are required to run the "reroute to source" algorithm on a small and large scale network. You are required to randomly generate the cost on each link and randomly select one node as the source and several other nodes as the destinations. Each router should maintain a table to show the incoming label associated with incoming port and outgoing labels***

[image]

*Picture above for reference. Each router at each node should maintain an MPLS table. Since the "reroute to source" algorithm is actually unicast, there is no need to extend the table.*

All I need is ideas. I have a very good understanding of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm but I feel like there's a gap in my understanding of how multicast incorporates such algorithm.

So, assuming my network is bidirectional, the algorithm will find the shortest path from each source to destination and assign labels along this path. Then, when all the shortest paths have been found, I just need to merge these paths and form a tree which would the be used for the multicast routing.

Do you guys have anything I could look at to give me ideas for a simulation? Or any suggestions based on experience. I just want to understand what I have to do

Comment: What does this code have to do with routing? What's the problem you're having?

Comment: @G.Bach I rewrote the question, hope it's a bit clearer now!